# Exclude activity types in fetchxml in multiple environments

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, fetch

I created a report that displays many activitypointers of an account. My FetchXML looks like the following:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="activitypointer">
        <attribute name="activityid" />
        <attribute name="scheduledstart" />
        <attribute name="actualend" />
        <attribute name="activitytypecode" />
        <attribute name="ownerid" />
        <attribute name="statecode" />
        <attribute name="subject" />
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="activitytypecode" operator="not-in">
                <value>10013</value> <!-- Custom activity entity-->
                <value>10001</value> <!-- Custom activity entity-->
                <value>4214</value> <!-- Service appointment entity -->
            </condition>
        </filter>
        <order attribute="createdon" descending="true" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Everything works fine till I deploy the report to production environment, because in that environment our custom activity entities have different activitytype codes.

Is there an simpler way than deploying individual reports to every environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by creating a new entity (like a 'key-value' entity), containing only two attributes. 
I added 3 Records:

```
key                            | value
---------------------------------------
exclude_activitytype_record    | 10001
exclude_activitytype_record    | 10013
exclude_activitytype_record    | 4214
```

Then I created a new dataset in the report using the following fetch:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" 
       distinct="false">
  <entity name="new_entity">
    <attribute name="new_inovaluesid" />
    <attribute name="new_value" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="new_parameter" 
                 operator="eq" 
                 value="excluded_activitytype_record" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

After that I added a new report parameter with following definition:

```
Name: ExcludedActivitytypes
Type: Integer
Allow multiple values: true
Visbility: hidden

Default values: Values from query
  Dataset: NewDatasetName
  Value field: new_value
```

In next step I modified the first query:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" 
       distinct="false">
  <entity name="activitypointer">
        <attribute name="activityid" />
        <attribute name="scheduledstart" />
        <attribute name="actualend" />
        <attribute name="activitytypecode" />
        <attribute name="ownerid" />
        <attribute name="statecode" />
        <attribute name="subject" />
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="activitytypecode" 
                               operator="not-in" 
                               value="@ExcludedActivities" />   
        </filter>
        <order attribute="createdon" descending="true" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Now I only have to change the value of the records in each environment once and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Type Codes are numbered via the order in which they were created.  If you could take a backup of Prod and overwrite your other environments that would resolve the issue although it doesn't keep it from happening again.

Every other idea I can think of is pretty hack-y.

Comment: Did not work for me. A FormatException is thrown. 'Expected type of attribute value: System.Int32.'

Comment: Unfortunately that is noch possible because production environment is owned by a customer.